# msbuild configuration on Jenkins cluster installed on windows

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, pipeline

I have jenkins installed on windows machine and trying to create pipeline for .net project.

The msbuild is not working on Jenkins pipeline and giving error msbuild not recognised internal or external command.

I tried passing as a script

```
Script{
def msbuild= tool name: 'ms',type:'MSBuild'
bat "\"${msbuild}\" ${workspace}//proj.sln /nologo /nr:false /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p: Configuration:Release /t:Clean"
}
```

As well in just pipeline formats

```
Step{
bat "ms ${workspace}//proj.sln /nologo /nr:false /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p: Configuration:Release /t:Clean"

}
```

In the pipeline but it is not able to find msbuild even though it is configured Global Tool and giving the same name in tool name,but not working.

However when tried as a freestyle project and tried building, i was able to list the msbuild configuration from drop-down to fetch 'ms'

Passed build file as ${workspace}//proj.sln

Command line parameters as
`nologo /nr:false /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p: Configuration:Release /t:Clean`

It was able to build correctly without any issues.

Not sure why it is not getting resolved in pipeline?

Any suggestions to fix this is helpful.

Tried giving the msbuild executable location from .Net application but it is a different system, it did not work.

Comment: have you tried specify the full path to the msbuild executable in the command like:
`sh 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\msbuild ${workspace}//proj.sln /nologo /nr:false /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:Configuration=Release /t:Clean'
`

Comment: Getting error "C:\Program' is not recognized as an iternal or external command,where as it works fine in freestyle project and able to list the build tool and command is also working. However, in pipeline it is throwing errors and jenkins version is 2.375.1